# NodeJS require() is generating errors

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I'm using

```
WebStorm 2017.1.4  
Build #WS-171.4694.29, built on June 7, 2017  
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b21 amd64  
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o  
Windows 8.1 6.3
```

This line:

```
var args = require('minimist'){process.argv.slice(2)};
```

Generates such errors:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {  
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)  
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)  
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)  
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)  
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)  
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)  
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)  
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)  
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)  
    at Object.<anonymous>   
(C:\Users\AltairSonOfDarkness\WebstormProjects\MMO\server.js:5:1)
```

I do know what the line is supposed to do, but i'm fairly new to node.js, so I have little idea what's happening, and even less on how to fix this.
I'd appreciate help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong syntax (this is not allowed in JavaScript), for how to use specific npm module please look on module documentation page on npm page here it will be this address: https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist.

For your use case please use this syntax.

```
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
console.dir(argv);
```